# PHP Upload an Image does not work

Tags: php, html, image, upload, xampp

I have a new Problem. I want to upload an Image from my Webpage in to a Folder on the Server (i'm using XAMPP).

I tryed a lot of examples also these two from php.net and w3schools.com but it does not work and I don't know why. -_-

This is the Code I'm using now:

```
$target_dir = "./uploads/images/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["thumbnail"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES["thumbnail"]["tmp_name"]);
                if($check !== false) {
                    $text = $text . "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                } else {
                    $text = $text . "File is not an image.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            }
            // Check if file already exists
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                $text = $text . "Sorry, file already exists.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check file size
            if ($_FILES["thumbnail"]["size"] > 500000) {
                $text = $text . "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Allow certain file formats
            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                $text = $text . "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                $text = $text . "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["thumbnail"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    $text = $text . "The file ". basename( $_FILES["thumbnail"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                } else {
                    $text = $text . "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
            }
```

This is the Example from w3schools.

The Variable $text is only to see in the url what happend.
The inputfield for the file is called: thumbnail

I think I don't get an image from the page, because when I write this:

```
$text = $text . "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file: ". basename( $_FILES["thumbnail"]["name"]). " Text ";
```

I get nothing between: file: & Text

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

===================== EDIT =====================

Here is the HTML Content:

```
<form id="postform" name="postform" action="?track=7" method="POST">
    <label for="thumbnail" class="forinput">Thumbnail <span class="info">Das Bild wir auf 250px : 250px skaliert</span></label>
    <input class="addMovieFormFile" id="thumbnail" type="file" name="thumbnail">
    <input type="submit" value="FILM HINZUFÜGEN" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: show us your html content

Comment: Post your html form

Comment: @Blueblazer172
I did this in the Edit part :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "**enctype="multipart/form-data**".

Please use this in your form like this.

```
<form id="postform" name="postform" action="?track=7" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Without using this you can not retrieve the file data.

Hope this will work for you.